# How to exclude CSS styling for headers inside a DIV with a certain class?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Suppose I have a header inside `<div>` with a certain class and I don't want a certain effect to apply to them, how do I exclude them with CSS?

Below the code:

```css
h2:not(.article) {
    font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="article">
    <h2>Title<h2>
</div>
```

But it still doesn't work and the `<h2>` inside `.article` div is still getting affected.

Comment: `:not(.article) > h2 {}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<h2>` isn't closed properly. The `:not()` pseudo class is backwards. Below is an example of how to use it.

```css
.article {
  font-size: 25px;
}

:not(.article)>h2 {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="article">
  <h2>Title 1</h2>
</div>
<div>
  <h2>Title 2</h2>
</div>
```